Multiple Slicers with Multiple Selection in each with AND condition in Power Bi
I am working on a model that filters items based on the criteria given in the slicers. In this I want to filter the item through three slicers

Hierarchy Slicer
Attribute Slicer
Attribute Value Slicer

As an example, let's say in second slicer I want to filter an item using two attributes (STANDARD, FINISH) with values (ISO 4014, NO SURFACE TREATMENT). Meaning I want to filter (see) the item which has ISO 4014 as STANDARD and NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH.
But when I try to do this (refer screen shot) it is not filtering for the 'AND' condition. It is filtering for 'OR' condition (i.e it filters all materials which has either NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH 'OR' STANDARD as ISO 4014, which I don't want.
I want to filter the material which has both NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH and ISO 4014 as STANDARD. How can I achieve my requirement? 
I have tried applying the DAX measures in slicers as per these YouTube video and blog. But it didn't help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tONOosN1xAs
2.https://radacad.com/slicer-with-and-condition-in-power-bi
I am open to any suggestions to achieve my end result.

https://superuser.com/users/1247873/mayukh-bhattacharya @Mayukh Bhattacharya any idea on the above query?

I can't say how to do it, but I it seems clear to me that the DAX for getting the attribute value is still listing individual values (making it an or) instead of combining them (making it and). I suggest you edit your post to include the DAX transformation you are attempting to use.

@gns100 I am a newbie to PowerBi and didn't write any DAX code to achieve my result. I referred this link https://radacad.com/slicer-with-and-condition-in-power-bi - But couldn't arrive at any solution. Is there any possibility, that I can achieve my result without DAX code itself?

I am in no way an expert on powerBI either, moving this to their forum would probably get you an instant answer. Having said that, based on your screenshot, I believe the key is the fifth and sixth rows which is identical except for the last two columns. I think you want to transform the 5th column as headers using the 6th column as the data fields. That should get you almost all the way there. Good luck.

@gns100 Which is the correct forum to ask this powerbi questions? Can you please share me the link?

It is not clear how you would expect the code to know which attribute goes with which name - what stops it matching ISO 4014 as a Finish? I think you might be able to achieve this with an intermediate table (that you create from your data source) with every combination of these and a concatenated column. In your fact table, also concatenate these and then join on that - filtering the intermediate table with the slicers will then filter the fact table. I am still not sure how best to "pair up" the slicers though.
